# Wireless driver only works after plugging the cable in with a BCM4313

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 this week. I've had a couple of problems with my wireless card. After following some posts here on askubuntu I got it to work on a peculiar way:

When I start my laptop **without** the ethernet cable, I get stuck on the Ubuntu "loading" screen while the system is booting. It says "Waiting for network configuration". Then it stays like that for about 2 minutes and when it finally boots up, I have no network connection.

However, if I boot **with my ethernet cable plugged in**, it loads quickly and with my wireless working just fine!

I'm not sure what to do anymore, I want that the wireless card works despite the ethernet cable is in or not. So I'm asking for your help.

Here are the results from some commands that may be helpful, if you need more info let me know, please.

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: c8:0a:a9:df:ff:ad
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.032.00-NAPI duplex=half ip=192.168.0.167 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff memory:d0020000-d003ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:26:82:93:d6:c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:d2100000-d2103fff





rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no




sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 9602
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 4)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 41)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series]
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4200 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

I ran "nmcli dev list" on both cases.

Here is what I got when I ran it without having the ethernet cable (i.e. wireless not working)

```
Error: NetworkManager is not running.
```

This is what I got when I ran it when wireless was OK:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           802-11-wireless
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         brcmsmac
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:26:82:93:D6:C4
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.0/0000:06:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
AP1.SSID:                               'Rep Kaxota'
AP1.BSSID:                              00:19:5B:B4:F6:21
AP1.MODE:                               Infrastructure
AP1.FREQ:                               2437 MHz
AP1.RATE:                               54 MB/s
AP1.SIGNAL:                             45
AP1.SECURITY:                           WPA WPA2
AP1.ACTIVE:                             no
AP2.SSID:                               'RepAmnesia'
AP2.BSSID:                              C8:3A:35:08:88:D8
AP2.MODE:                               Infrastructure
AP2.FREQ:                               2412 MHz
AP2.RATE:                               54 MB/s
AP2.SIGNAL:                             75
AP2.SECURITY:                           WEP
AP2.ACTIVE:                             no
AP3.SSID:                               'Amnesia'
AP3.BSSID:                              1C:7E:E5:C2:B6:B8
AP3.MODE:                               Infrastructure
AP3.FREQ:                               2437 MHz
AP3.RATE:                               54 MB/s
AP3.SIGNAL:                             79
AP3.SECURITY:                           WEP
AP3.ACTIVE:                             yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.xxx.xxx/24, gw = 192.168.xxx.xxx
IP4.DNS[1]:                             200.204.xxx.xxx
IP4.DNS[2]:                             200.204.xxx.xxx
IP4.DNS[3]:                             192.168.xxx.xxx
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        expiry = 1345748643
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.xxx.xxx
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        routers = 192.168.xxx.xxx
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 604800
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.xxx.xxx
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        dhcp_renewal_time = 604780
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        domain_name_servers = 200.204.xxx.xxx 200.204.xxx.xxx 192.168.xxx.xxx
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 604780
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.xxx.xxx
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           802-3-ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8168
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         C8:0A:A9:DF:FF:AD
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     not connected
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
```

Adding more information (this was taken while booting normally, i.e. without cable):

Contents of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

(with the empty last line)

Contents of if-down.d ( I don`t know how to check the version. I suppose it's that v143 on the first line):

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v143)
"   /etc/network/if-down.d
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
../
avahi-autoipd*
resolvconf*
upstart*                                                                        
wpasupplicant@
```

Contents of if-up.d:
    " ============================================================================
    " Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v143)
    "   /etc/network/if-up.d
    "   Sorted by      name
    "   Sort sequence: [/]$,\,.h$,.c$,.cpp$,\~\=*$,*,.o$,\
    "   Quick Help: :help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
    " ============================================================================
    ../
    000resolvconf*
    avahi-autoipd*
    avahi-daemon*
    ntpdate*
    upstart*
    wpasupplicant@

Contents of /run/network directory:

```
matheus@matheus-laptop:/run/network$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  60 Sep  5 19:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 720 Sep  5 19:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   0 Sep  5 19:54 ifstate
```

Contents of ifstate: Empty

Thank you very much in advance!
Matheus

Comment: I would suggest running the command `nmcli dev list` two times:  first, run without the cable connected, when it's not  working, then run it again with the cable connected.  I won't guarantee that this will help, but it may provide useful information on addresses being used.

Comment: Hmmm... not really what I was hoping for.  One thing I notice is that the first two DNS addresses are external to your LAN, so you must have specified them explicitly, rather than using automatic settings?  Have you tried using full automatic DHCP in the IPV4 settings?  Also, are you actually using all 3 wireless connections?  I don't know whether that might cause problems, but if you're not using them all, it might simplify things to delete them.

Comment: Sorry, I fired up my notebook, and realize that the multiple wireless connections are probably normal.  But I also notice that your wired connection looks incomplete, and has no IP addresses.  It could be that the configuration for the "Network Connections" is incorrect for one or more of the connections.  I can't think of anything else.  Maybe someone with more detailed knowledge can come up with some suggestions.

Comment: Could you please add the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and mention the version of package ifupdown? I believe you are seeing a case where upstart `signal static-network-up` is not being emitted until you are plugging in your ethernet cable. When you are waiting what is the contents of the directory /run/network and the contents of /run/network/ifstate?